# How do you edit and build an import Bento?

Tags: bentoml

BentoML has `export` and `import` commands to move bentos from one repo to another. But it is recommended that one not edit bentos under `~/bentoml` (default bento repo location). So how should one go about editing a bento received from an `export` command?

I tried just unpacking the tarball and running `bentoml build` in the folder but that results in

```
Error: bentofile "bentofile.yaml" not found
```

There is a "bento.yaml" file in the untarred folder so I tried `bentoml build -f bento.yaml` but that results in a slew of other errors. It seems like there should be a fairly straightforward way to make an imported bento (or associated tarball) editable.

Answer (score 1):

Bentos are artifacts that are not meant to be edited. It is recommended to edit the source code where the bento was built from.